# Rope moves away

Tags: animation, bones, weight-painting

When i move bone, rope goes away from bow, i want to weld it at top and bottom.

[image]

Comment: I think we need more information about how this is rigged and why you expect the string to be attached to the end. Also, it would be good if you uploaded the blend file.

Comment: https://ufile.io/qiowo

Comment: The sting ends have weight from the "puller" bone. They should be weight painted to the end bones of the bow.